# Trying to add a view that displays a list of items with a particular attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am having trouble with an action. I have a list of machines in a database with has a column of dataType 'Bit' which is a serves a checkbox to state whether or not a machine has been delivered to site. I am trying to create a View that displays only items that have been marked as Delivered' but I am getting the below error

> [ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'itemDelivered' of non-nullable type 'System.Boolean' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult deliveredItems(Boolean)' in 'PreConReports.Controllers.MachineChecklistDBsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

My Full controller and Action for what I am trying to achieve.

```
public ActionResult deliveredItems(bool deliveredItem)
{
    var machineChecklist = from m in db.machineChecklist
                               select m;
    if (deliveredItem == true)
    {
        machineChecklist = machineChecklist.Where(p => p.itemDelivered);
    }
    else
    {
        return View(machineChecklist.ToList());
    }
    return View(machineChecklist.OrderBy(x => x.machineID));
    {
    }
}
```

---

```
namespace PreConReports.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class MachineChecklistDBsController : Controller
    {
        private machineChecklistContext db = new machineChecklistContext();

        // GET: MachineChecklistDBs
        public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
        {

            var machineChecklist = from m in db.machineChecklist
                                   select m;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                machineChecklist = machineChecklist.Where(s => s.machineID.Contains(searchString));
            }
            else
            {
                return View(machineChecklist.ToList());
            }
            return View(machineChecklist.OrderBy(x => x.machineID));
            { 

                }
            }

        //GET: MachineChecklistDBs/itemsDelivered/

        public ActionResult deliveredItems(bool deliveredItem)
        {

            var machineChecklist = from m in db.machineChecklist
                                   select m;
            if (deliveredItem == true)
            {
                machineChecklist = machineChecklist.Where(p => p.itemDelivered);

            }
            else
            {
                return View(machineChecklist.ToList());
            }
            return View(machineChecklist.OrderBy(x => x.machineID));
            {

            }
        }


        // GET: MachineChecklistDBs/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            MachineChecklistDB machineChecklistDB = db.machineChecklist.Find(id);
            if (machineChecklistDB == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(machineChecklistDB);
        }

        // GET: MachineChecklistDBs/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: MachineChecklistDBs/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,machineID,inMel,preCon,preConIssueDate,postCon,postConIssueDate,PUWERrequired,itemDelivered,dateOfDelivery")] MachineChecklistDB machineChecklistDB)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.machineChecklist.Add(machineChecklistDB);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(machineChecklistDB);
        }

        // GET: MachineChecklistDBs/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            MachineChecklistDB machineChecklistDB = db.machineChecklist.Find(id);
            if (machineChecklistDB == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(machineChecklistDB);
        }

        // POST: MachineChecklistDBs/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,machineID,inMel,preCon,preConIssueDate,postCon,postConIssueDate,PUWERrequired,itemDelivered,dateOfDelivery")] MachineChecklistDB machineChecklistDB)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(machineChecklistDB).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(machineChecklistDB);
        }

        // GET: MachineChecklistDBs/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            MachineChecklistDB machineChecklistDB = db.machineChecklist.Find(id);
            if (machineChecklistDB == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(machineChecklistDB);
        }

        // POST: MachineChecklistDBs/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            MachineChecklistDB machineChecklistDB = db.machineChecklist.Find(id);
            db.machineChecklist.Remove(machineChecklistDB);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the relevant code - how you call that method (the error is self explanatory - your not provide a value for parameter `deliveredItem`)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, I should have mentioned that I am pretty new to this and still trying to understand the fundamentals, and I do not fully understand your reply, would it be ok if i asked you to elaborate on it a bit? Thank you

Comment: The view you have shown is irrelevant. Somewhere in your code your calling that method but not providing a value for the parameter (and just enter `.../MachineChecklistDBs/deliveredItems?deliveredItem=true` in your address bar and you will see that it works fine

Comment: Yes, you are right, that works perfectly when putting the parameter in the address bar I will add the full controller class to my post as I am clearly missing something that is glaringly obvious to everyone else, thank you.

Comment: Yes, you are right, that works perfectly when putting the parameter in the address bar I will add the full controller class to my post as I am clearly missing something that is glaringly obvious to everyone else, thank you.

Comment: You need to debug your code. When does that error occur?

Comment: More of a workaround than a solution but I have added href="deliveredItems?deliveredItem=true" to the button that calls the view for now, which serves it's purpose. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action has the parameter bool deliveredItem.

This is a non nullable type and would then be a mandatory requirement for that action.  That is what the error message is indicating.

You can alter the method to something like.

```
    public ActionResult deliveredItems(bool deliveredItem = false)
    {

        var machineChecklist = from m in db.machineChecklist
                               select m;
        if (deliveredItem == true)
        {
            machineChecklist = machineChecklist.Where(p => p.itemDelivered);

        }
        else
        {
            return View(machineChecklist.ToList());
        }
        return View(machineChecklist.OrderBy(x => x.machineID));
     }
```

By providing a default argument any calls to the method will default to false and not give the error.  Also this will mean you don't have to provide the value in every link.

Comment: Absolutely spot on, I knew it would be something silly like that, but due to lack of experience I couldn't see the obvious, I had tried using 
(bool? deliveredItem), which loaded the page fine but displayed all results instead of just the ones with the deliveredItem attribute, but this works a treat. I have much to learn, thank you very much.